# after pin local-date still cant use it in time_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i go through video of turorial from main page rubyonrails.org, i write in console
./bin/importmap pin local-time
in importmap.rb appear:

```
pin "local-time", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:local-time@2.1.0/app/assets/javascripts/local-time.js"
```

but when i try use it in time tag in post.html.erb:

```
Posted: <%= time_tag post.created_at, "data-local": "time-ago" %>
```

appear "Posted: September 09, 2022 10:19" but not "5 minutes ago" or something like this. Basically in projects very simple i just add scaffold post, text rich, here link for it https://github.com/kukla1989/rubyonrails (i will delete it after problem will solve). Sorry if something wrong, i only begin learn rails

i checked 10 times everething like in tutorial, also seems there are no similar problems

Comment: Not sure about `time_tag`, but i think you can use `time_ago_in_words`. In your case, that would be: `Posted: <%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %>`

Comment: Also, i don't see how a .js file (client side) could have anything to do with the rails method `time_tag` (server side).

Comment: time_ago_in_words don't localize time, for example, if you are from America your time will differ by 5 hours. About js when I try to explain to you how it works I started to rewatch the video and realized that at the beginning of the speech of local time I miss something important, see the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import LocalTime in `app/javascript/application.js`

```js
// Configure your import map in config/importmap.rb. Read more: https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import "controllers"
import "trix"
import "@rails/actiontext"
// import LocalTime
import LocalTime from "local-time"
LocalTime.start()
```